# Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/impl/conn/AbstractClientConnAdapter;

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dex

### The problem:

Gradle error: "Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/impl/conn/AbstractClientConnAdapter;"

### The question:

The error message doesn't include much detail. Is there a way to find out which files it's referring to? How can I narrow this down? I'm hoping there's an easy way to do this.

### What I've tried:

Putting this for each library in the Gradle file:

```
exclude module: 'org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter'
```

E.g.

```
    implementation (group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.2') {
        exclude module: 'org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter'
    }
```

However this doesn't seem to make a difference as I still get the error. I have a multi module project but I'm only running "assemble" on one module which I believe is the problem. There are only 4 library dependencies and no local jars for this module.

What am I not understanding about how "exclude works"? If they're all excluded then where is it coming from?

## Other Info:

This is an Android project but the module I'm having the problem with is a pure Java module.

I'm using Android Studio 3.0.

p.s. what is the "L" before org in the error?

Comment: Did you figure out the issue?

Comment: I don't remember. I don't think I solved it directly as I would have added an answer. I think maybe I found a different library to use instead. But I don't have access to that project anymore so I can't look to find out. I wonder if you find an answer maybe I can transfer the question to you since I won't be able to verify the answer.

Comment: an issue here may be that "exclude module: 'org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter'" isn't a module, it's a specific class. I'm also searching if a class can be excluded. But I'm not sure if it's possible like that.

Comment: You might be right. I'm not working on that project or at that company anymore so I can't test it but if you can confirm this is the problem I'll award you the points.